# Right-click context menu not consistently "sticky"

Tags: macbook-pro, multi-touch

I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 on a 2008 MBP.

The right-click on my mousepad activates the context menu.  A single right-click displays the menu, and it stays visible until I make a selection or click away from the menu.

For the last several months the right-click is no longer consistently "sticky." I.e., the context menu will disappear unless I click and hold.  This is a hassle because it means a more complicated multi-touch manipulation of the mousepad.

I've scoured this forum as well as Google without finding an answer.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Never heard of such an issue before. Have you tried turn off secondary click in the trackpad prefs and re-enable it again? If you click AND hold the right mouse button it will alway disappear when you release the button, but if you just click it once the context menu should stay (as you already mentioned). Do you have any other software installed, that may control the "speed" of a mouseclick?

Comment: If you enable the two-fingered tap method for context menus (temporarily or otherwise -- IIRC you can still enable both methods at the same time in 10.6), does the context menu persist when you open it that way? If so, I suspect it could be an issue with the trackpad itself, especially if the behaviour isn't consistent.

Comment: Thanks! Turning off and turning on the secondary click option in System Preferences >> Trackpad seems to have done it. BTW: no other software installed. Will keep trying it to make sure the solution is "sticky" as well. Many thanks.

Comment: This started happening on my Macmini on Catalina.  Also, when I go into the system preferences, it does not have settings for the built-in trackpad.  If I select, it say's no trackpad found.  Same with the mouse.  Very distressing and frustrating.